# What would cause the Goutte driver to not follow a redirect?

Tags: phpunit, mink

I have a PHPUnit Mink test that is ensuring that some HTTP redirects are in place.

This is whittled down, but the test essentially looks like, where `testRedirect()` is fed by a `@dataProvider`:

```
class Testbase extends BrowserTestCase {

  public static $browsers = [
    [
      'driver' => 'goutte',
    ],
  ];

  public function testRedirect($from, $to) {
    $session = $this->getSession();
    $session->visit($from);

    $this->assertEquals(200, $session->getDriver()->getStatusCode(), sprintf('Final destination from %s was a 200', $to));
    $this->assertEquals($to, $session->getCurrentUrl(), sprintf('Redirected from %s to %s', $from, $to));
  }

}
```

This works fine for the redirects that are handled on the webserver itself (eg, mod_rewrite ones).  However, some of the redirects I need to check are handled by the DNS provider (I don't control this, but I think it is NetNames).

If I test the redirect with wget, it looks fine

```
$ wget --max-redirect=0 http://example1.com/
Resolving example1.com... A.B.C.D
Connecting to example1.com|A.B.C.D|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://example2.com/some/path?foo=bar [following]
0 redirections exceeded.
```

However, when I dump the response from my test the headers are

```
Date: Thu, 06 Sep 2018 15:37:47 GMT
Content-Length: 94
X-Powered-By: Servlet/2.4 JSP/2.0
```

and the response is

```
<head>
<title></title>
<meta name="revised" content="1.1.7">
</head>
<body></body>
```

with a 200 status code.

Do I need to explicitly set a request header?  I tried

```
$session->setRequestHeader('Host', 'example1.com');
```

but that didn't help.

What can cause this?

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be a weird situation with the Host header, I think on the receiving end.

My test provider had some hostnames with uppercase characters in them, eg "http://Example1.com/".  I had to update the test function to be

```
public function testRedirect($from, $to) {
  $parts = parse_url($from);
  $host = strtolower($parts['host']);

  $session = $this->getSession();
  $session->setRequestHeader('Host', $host);
  $session->visit($from);

  $this->assertEquals(200, $session->getDriver()->getStatusCode(), sprintf('Final destination from %s was a 200', $to));
  $this->assertEquals($to, $session->getCurrentUrl(), sprintf('Redirected from %s to %s', $from, $to));
}
```

to force the Host header to be lowercase.